# Vixie Cron Timezone

Tags: cron, timezone

I have read in the manual that this cron implementation handles timezone, but I am not sure how exactly, here are my tests:

First:

```
$ crontab -e
  TZ=PST8PDT
  * 14 * * * echo `date` >> ~/test.txt
  * * * * * echo qwe`date` >> ~/test.txt
```

It prints in `~/test.txt`:

```
qweThu Mar 13 14:35:02 PDT 2014
qweThu Mar 13 14:36:02 PDT 2014
qweThu Mar 13 14:37:01 PDT 2014
```

Note the first entry is not the one that is running, even when in `PST8PDT` time is `14` hours.

Second test:

```
$ crontab -e
  TZ=PST8PDT
  CRON_TZ=PST8PDT
  * 14 * * * echo `date` >> ~/test.txt
  * * * * * echo qwe`date` >> ~/test.txt
```

Same output.

How do I execute a command in `PST8PDT`, i.e, making the entry with `14` to echo in my file.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that `PST8PDT` isn't being recognised as a valid timezone identifier. It seems to have dropped out of the IANA database.

Try using:

1. A timezone [identifier from the IANA database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), e.g. `"America/Los Angeles"`.
2. A timezone [abbreviation from the (semi)-standard list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), e.g. `WST`.

Also double-check that your version of cron actually supports `CRON_TZ`. If it is supported it should be mentioned in the cron man page on your system (`man cron`).